# Syntax error when exectuting bash shell script from busybox

Tags: bash, busybox

Syntax error when executing a bash shell script from busybox

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
for dev in `cat /proc/partitions | awk '{print $4}'`; do
if cmp -s <(head -c 2 /dev/$dev) <(echo -n -e '\x38\x6e')
then
echo "OK"
break
fi
done
```

**Error line 3**

> Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Busybox doesn't do bash, it only has a minimal sh-like shell. The `<()` syntax is specific to bash (and some other similar shells). It won't work with POSIX sh or busybox sh or any other minimal shell. That's why you're getting that error.

To get your script to work with busyboxh sh, try:

```
match=$'\x38\x63'
for dev in $(awk '/[0-9]/{print $NF}' /proc/partitions); do
        first=$(head -c 2 /dev/$dev)
        if [ "$first" = "$match" ]
        then
                echo "OK"
                break
        fi
done
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't work, it executes `echo "OK"` even if there is no match

Comment: @Kikapi that's odd. It does work on my system. Try printing out the values of `$match` and `$first`. Are they actually different? Are they empty perhaps?

Comment: my bad it is working.

Comment: +1. Try `match=$'\x38\x63'` (it works even in busybox sh).  Also, `for dev in $(awk '!/major|^$/ {print $4}' /proc/partitions); do ...`